# User Model return null for the user name

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to display the users name using blade, but Its says null.

This is the controller

```
 public function edit(Project $project)
{
    //
    $project = Project::findOrFail($project->id);
   
    $assignees = User::with('roles')->get();
 
    
    return view('projects.edit',['project'=>$project,'assignees'=>$assignees]);
}
```

When I `dd($assignees)` all the columns appears including the name column.

```
 #attributes: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "name" => "Kitten Moose"
    "email" => "kitten@karata.com"
    "email_verified_at" => null
    "password" => "$2y$10$iG4EZBq13ExGOVIrGNhEQeVvordWc3ibWfYgdaq6x0wqefetqXixe"
    "remember_token" => null
    "created_at" => "2020-07-03 05:11:56"
    "updated_at" => "2020-07-11 09:37:49"
    "team_id" => 3
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
```

On blade:

```
 <div class="form-group">
       <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Assignee</label>
        <select name="assignee_id" class="js-example-basic-single">
              <option value="&nbsp;">Select</option>
                  @foreach($assignees as $assignee)
                       <option value="{{$assignee->id}}">{{$assignee->name}}</option>
                  @endforeach

       </select>
 </div>
```

Using the blade above, I get `{"id":1,"name":null`} everything else displays correctly

I'm not sure if this could be caused by the model, but I have this in the user model:

```
 public function assignee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218360/discussion-on-question-by-user1783675-user-model-return-null-for-the-user-name).

Comment: Please share with us the output of this: ```{{ dd($assignee) }}``` in ```edit.blade.php``` 
to see what is the value of the variable that you are trying to loop.

Comment: @leo95batista It's shared on the question.  I went through the application and realised that the issue wasn't just with the one controller, but rather all controller where a user's name is to be displayed